# Изменение цвета текста в C++

Tags: c++, linux

Люди, подскажите, пожалуйста, как в С++ изменить цвет текста, чтобы работал в линусковой консоли, а везде про винду да про винду.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно просто поменять цвет вывода и не хочется подключать ncurses, то самое простое - это использовать цветовые escape-последовательности. Выглядит это так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    printf("\033[31mThis is red.\033[0m\n");
    printf("\033[32mThis is green.\033[0m\n");
    printf("\033[34mThis is blue.\033[0m\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#define C_Reset      0
#define C_Bold       1
#define C_Under      2
#define C_Invers     3
#define C_Normal     4
#define C_Black      4
#define C_Red        5
#define C_Green      6
#define C_Brown      7
#define C_Blue       8
#define C_Magenta    9
#define C_Cyan       10
#define C_Light      11
#define N_COLORS     C_Light+1

static int tcolor [N_COLORS] = {
 0,  1,  4,  7, 30, 31, 
 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37 };

fprintf (out,"\033[%dm",tcolor[color]);
```

color это один из C_Red, C_Green и т.д.  Названия придуманы мной, м.б. они д.б. другими. Это коды на которые эмулятор терминала в Linux RedHat Gnome адекватно реагировал.